# Excel VBA - Combine repeating columns data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master spreadsheet of criteria that I need to consolidate and am unsure of how to automate this.

The data looks like this:

```
Unique ID | Info | Info 2 | Info 3 | Criteria 1 | Info for Criteria 1 | Criteria 2 | Info for Criteria 2
1234      | ABC  | 1/1/20 | Active | Plan 1     | 1/1/2020            | Plan 2     | 3/15/2020
4567      | DEF  | 2/1/20 | Active | Plan 1     | 1/5/2020            | Plan 2     | 2/15/2020
9874      | HJD  | 2/1/20 | Active | Plan 1     | 3/5/2020            |            | 

And I need it to look like this:

Unique ID | Info | Info 2 | Info 3 | Criteria 1 | Info for Criteria 1 
1234      | ABC  | 1/1/20 | Active | Plan 1     | 1/1/2020            
1234      | ABC  | 1/1/20 | Active | Plan 2     | 3/15/2020          
4567      | DEF  | 2/1/20 | Active | Plan 1     | 1/5/2020            
4567      | DEF  | 2/1/20 | Active | Plan 2     | 2/15/2020           
9874      | HJD  | 2/1/20 | Active | Plan 1     | 3/5/2020
```

The criteria and the information columns specific to the criteria are repeating across columns and I need all that information to be stacked in rows with the first set of data (cols 1 through 4) repeating.

I don't know what would be the most efficient way to automate this process. Currently, it's a lot of copying and pasting. I'd like to write a macro that would go through the repeating criteria and copy the information and paste it at the bottom of the data. The table is always in the the same format with the same number of repeating criteria (27).

Any nudge in the right direction would be so incredibly appreciated.

Comment: "Any nudge in the right direction would be so incredibly appreciated." You can use PowerQuery and transpose the columns.

Comment: @Andreas this was my initial plan, however, nobody else on my team knows PowerQuery so I'm trying to automate it so everyone can scrub this file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Macro change worksheet and workbook name in macro. Please Make Backup of Your Data before using macro because if you dont like the Result then it will not reverse using undo.

```
Private Sub combine()
Dim lastdata As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
lastdata = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set wb = Workbooks("book1.xlsm") 'Change Workbook Name
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("sheet1") 'Change Worksheet Name
For i = lastdata To 2 Step -1
If ws1.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column > 6 Then
ws1.Rows(i).Insert
ws1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 1)
ws1.Cells(i + 1, 7).Resize(1, 2).Cut Destination:=Cells(i, 5)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you so much! This definitely puts me on track for expanding this to all the other criteria in the workbook.